# Класс который регистрирует все свои объекты с++

Tags: c++

Подскажите.
Написать программу, которая реализует статические компоненты класса и демонстрирует работу с ними.
Создать класс, который регистрирует все свои объекты - это как?

Comment: Это значит класс, конструктор которого при создании нового объекта записывает созданный объект в статическое свойство этого класса. Вроде бы.

Comment: Что понимается под "регистрирует"? Например, в простейшем случае можно сделать просто статический счетчик, который будет считать количество созданных экземпляров. Этого достаточно или что-то более сложное требуется?

Comment: @Voidificator согласен. Регистрировать тоже по-разному можно.

Comment: По-идее должен просто считать сколько я объектов создал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
class A
{
    int x;
    static int count;
  public:
    A(int x)
    {
        this->x = x;
        count++;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        count--;
    }
    static int quantity()
    {
        return count;
    }
};
int A::count = 0;
int main()
{
    cout << "Count object: " << A::quantity() << endl;
    A* p1, *p2, *p3;
    p1 = new A(1);
    p2 = new A(2);
    p3 = new A(3);
    cout << "Count object: " << A::quantity() << endl;
    delete p1;
    delete p2;
    cout << "Count object: " << A::quantity() << endl;
    delete p3;
    cout << "Count object: " << A::quantity() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Поменяем ваш код самую малость: https://ideone.com/faKgLf Нехорошо получается, да? :) Еще раз посмотрите, что я в своем ответе вам написал внизу, курсивом...

Comment: @Ivan, вас в ВУЗе учать new/delete направо и налево везде использовать? Работайте со стеком если нет явной причины для динамической алокации.

Comment: Harry, спасибо большое. Я понял где ошибся, переписал и все правильно работает.

Comment: подскажите, почему эту часть кода '''int A::count = 0;''' нужно вставлять именно перед main()?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Counter
{
    ...
    static int count;
    ...
    Counter() { ++count; ...}
    Counter(const Counter&) { ++count; ...}
    ...
    ~Counter() { --count; ... }

};

int Counter::count = 0;
```

От вас явно ждут чего-то такого. Возможно, не с непосредственным увеличением счетчика, а со статическими функциями для увеличения и уменьшения, и для возврата общего количества.

Только не забудьте увеличивать счетчик *в каждом конструкторе*.

Comment: Я реализовал так

Comment: Ниже ответил, не знаю как в ответе вставить свой код.